# Asp.net MVC 5 redirect to Account/Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC. I have MVC version 5.2.2.0

I attached Authorize attribute to an action method Index() in Employee controller.

In the Web.config file, I changed authentication tag data as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginurl="~/Authentication/Login"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

What is expected is that when localhost:port/Employee/Index is accessed, the user should be redirected to localhost:port/Authentication/Login

But it is redirecting to localhost:port/Account/Login

By looking at other links, I tried the following things:

1.Added

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/Authentication/Login" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
```

to appSettings section of Web.config

2.Changed IIS 8 Anonymous Authentication from Specific User to Application Pool Identity

3.When the above two didn't work, I changed authentication tag to

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

But none worked.

**EDIT**
Don't do the things 1, 2, 3 I mentioned above. Just do the changes mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that  you will have the OWIN middleware configured by default to redirect to "/Account/Login" for cookie authentication.

Open /AppStart/Startup.Auth.cs and edit the following block of code to target our own URL :-

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });            
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Comment: Do you mean Startup.cs or Startup.Auth.cs? I suppose it is Startup.Auth.cs

Comment: Yes, it's Startup.Auth.cs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this has changed. I'm learning ASP.NET 5 (dnx451 and MVC 6.0.0-rc1-final) and there you have to define the default redirect adress for login in the service: "ConfigureServices" method not in the "Configure" method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(configure =>
        {
            //add some requirements
            configure.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            configure.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            //define the default page if a call must be [Autorized]
            configure.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath =  "/Auth/Login"; 
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthContext>(); //use entity framework to store the user data
}
```

Comment: Was looking for that for quite a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Comment the following line out in web.config and then it won't go to "Account/Login" automatically. I tested in VS2015 and it works fine.

Line to be commented out:

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
```