# Login request redirects to Account/Login?ReturnUrl

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So basically I have this simple form in my index page:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeUserName", "Manage", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input name="newUserName" value="@ViewBag.CurrentUser.NickName" type="text" class="enterName" placeholder="Enter name" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />
    <button class="enter-button">Change Name!</button>
}
```

and this is my `ChangeUserName` action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeUserName(string newUserName, int roomId)
{
    bool isLogged = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    if(!isLogged)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("!isLogged");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    if (!ApplicationUserManager.IsUserNameValid(newUserName))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Your nickname must be between 2 and 10 english character or letters.");
        TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    user.NickName = newUserName;


    // Persist the name in the database
    var identityResult = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    // Can happen for example by duplicate username
    if(!identityResult.Succeeded)
    {
        AddErrors(identityResult);
        TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // Updates the username in the Cookies ( re-loggin )
    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, false);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Room", new { id = roomId });

}
```

Nowhere in the `ChangeUserName` action there's a `RedirectToAction` to Account/Login, but it happens sometimes, mainly if I don't use the website for several hours and then click on the "change name" button, it redirects to:

Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FManage%2FChangeUserName

From what I've found on the internet, this questions might help:

[MVC4 Windows Authentication Redirect to Account/Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060533/mvc4-windows-authentication-redirect-to-account-login/)

[Asp.net MVC 5 redirect to Account/Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219759/asp-net-mvc-5-redirect-to-account-login)

But I couldn't really tell if it's match my issue and I honestly didn't understand these answer, should I just remove these pieces of code from Startup.auth.cs?

**Note: Adding my startup file:**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365)
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your startup.cs file

Comment: @OffirPe'er added.

Comment: `Login request redirects to Account/Login?ReturnUrl` I'd suggest changing your title since it may be misleading. It seems you aren't trying to login.

Comment: `mainly if I don't use the website for several hours and then click on the "change name" button` Almost certainly you are effectively 'logged out', and the button is the first thing you did after being logged out. If instead you went to any other URL you'd see the same behaviour (redirected to login page).

Comment: @mjwills why would it logged out if I've set the ExpireTimeSpan to be 1 year? How could I solve that problem so it won't redirect to Account/Login ?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by:

1. Put the following in app settings:

```
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/LogOn" />
```

2. You can use below app settings in web.config file.

```
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

3. If you have used WebMatrix.*.dll in _bin_deployableAssemblies and bin folders respectively, then remove those DLLs.